# Which OpenGL version is correct?

Tags: graphics, gpu

I want to install certain software and this requires system which supports at least OpenGL 2.1. Executing `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL Version"` returns `OpenGL version string: 2.1 INTEL-10.24.45`. On the other hand, according to Apple's documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823 my laptop, which is a Macbook Pro 13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports, has OpenGL 4.1 installed. Which one should I trust?

Comment: You kind of have to 'trust' both. Apple's native OpenGL isn't supported by a lot of 3rd party software, only the legacy v2.1 Unless you can find documentation somewhere on precisely which version it needs for Mac, then I'd just install it & see how it goes.

Comment: It's actually Blender that I want to install and the recommended setting (which is better than the minimum setting) suggests OpenGL 3.2.

Comment: Blender works fine on Mac, though idk what version of OGL is thinks it's using.